# Services and Logic Apps

Tags: console, console-application, azure-logic-apps, jobs, worker-service

On the onpremises servers, we have console/worker services batch job (services) deployed. Can I use the logic APP to keep track of them?
When I mention tracking, I mean

1. remotely activating any console  job/service
2. remotely stopping the  job/service
3. Skipping jobs, halting job/service, and disabling job/service
4. Skipping jobs, halting job/service, and disabling job/service
5. If any exceptions are thrown, get the service(job) error status.
   Which Microsoft tool may be used in this situation? We intend to create a dashboard that will allow us to remotely monitor and control all of our services. My question is, can we make use of Logic App in this circumstance in any way?

Comment: There are/will be multiple ways to do what you're talking about but for simplicity, you may want to decouple the on-prem jobs with LogicApps.  By that I mean, if you read this document ... https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-connection ... there are connectors that can be used to access on-prem data but they're used to pull/push.  You could always use one of those systems as a trigger point but something like ServiceBus/Storage Queues may be a better/easier option where you drop a message on from the cloud and then pick it up using an on-prem listener.

Answer (score -1):

- Yes, you can connect to Azure Logic Apps through On-prem using **Data Gateways**.

> After you [install the  *on-premises data gateway*  on a local computer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install) and before you can access data sources on premises from your logic apps, you have to create a gateway resource in Azure for your gateway installation. You can then select this gateway resource in the triggers and actions that you want to use for the [on-premises connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/managed#on-premises-connectors) available in Azure Logic Apps. Azure Logic Apps supports read and write operations through the data gateway. However, these operations have [limits on their payload size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/gateway/service-gateway-onprem#considerations).

[image]

- As Suggested by [Skin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772095/skin), Yes there are many ways to connect to On-prem Data to logic app and the best and easy way would be connecting it through **Service Bus/Storage Queue**.
- You can refer this [**Microsoft Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-connection) for more information.

Comment: Hey [Nair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2786308/nair), has it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Comment: My inquiry is about utilizing logic app to manage a console program that I have installed on a PC. Like start the console app/ Stop and pause and all

Comment: The document which I provided in the answer will be helpful in resolving your issue

Comment: Sorry Sai. I am not able to locate the solution in the document you have mentioned, May be i am looking in a wrong place. could u pls help me with the exact area where i should explore for the solution?